# paypal ipn micah's php class

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

i know there's plenty of question with this subject , i am playing around with paypal IPN for almost 3 hours now and with no success. This is a long question , i really appreciate if someone can read it through.

im trying to create a simple online service , which a user goes to my site , click a paypal payment button and will be brought to paypal for them to make the payment. After payment , they will be brought back to a page which verifies if they paid or not. If paid , it display the sign up page which is in the same (php file) , if not , the user will be redirected back to the home page.

i followed the tutorial here:
http://www.micahcarrick.com/paypal-ipn-with-php.html

I put everything into the same directory , (ipnlistener.php , ipn.php , ipn-errors.log) and an index.html which stores the **BUY NOW button** code which is:

```
<html>
<title>Test IPN</title>
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" 
    method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="testmailsandbox@domain.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Item">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="50">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://mysite.com/ipn/">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://mysite.com/ipn/ipn.php">
    <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" 
        border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
</html>
```

I did not touched the `ipnlistener.php` file as it is a class being used by `ipn.php`

**My ipn.php file:**

```
/**
 *  @package    PHP-PayPal-IPN
 *  @author     Micah Carrick
 *  @copyright  (c) 2011 - Micah Carrick
 *  @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
 */

    ini_set('log_errors', true);
    ini_set('error_log','ipn_errors.log');


    // instantiate the IpnListener class
    include('ipnlistener.php');
    $listener = new IpnListener();


    /*
    When you are testing your IPN script you should be using a PayPal "Sandbox"
    account: https://developer.paypal.com
    When you are ready to go live change use_sandbox to false.
    */
    $listener->use_sandbox = true;


    try {
        $listener->requirePostMethod();
        $verified = $listener->processIpn();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        error_log($e->getMessage());
        exit(0);
    }


    /*
    The processIpn() method returned true if the IPN was "VERIFIED" and false if it
    was "INVALID".
    */
    if ($verified) {
        // 1. Make sure the payment status is "Completed" 
        if ($_POST['payment_status'] != 'Completed') { 
            // simply ignore any IPN that is not completed
            exit(0); 
        }

        // 2. Make sure seller email matches your primary account email.
        if ($_POST['receiver_email'] != 'testmailsandbox@domain.com') {
            $errmsg .= "'receiver_email' does not match: ";
            $errmsg .= $_POST['receiver_email']."\n";
        }

        // 3. Make sure the amount(s) paid match
        if ($_POST['mc_gross'] != '50') {
            $errmsg .= "'mc_gross' does not match: ";
            $errmsg .= $_POST['mc_gross']."\n";
        }

        // 4. Make sure the currency code matches
        if ($_POST['mc_currency'] != 'USD') {
            $errmsg .= "'mc_currency' does not match: ";
            $errmsg .= $_POST['mc_currency']."\n";
        }

        // TODO: Check for duplicate txn_id

        if (!empty($errmsg)) {

            // manually investigate errors from the fraud checking
            $body = "IPN failed fraud checks: \n$errmsg\n\n";
            $body .= $listener->getTextReport();
            mail('myemail@domain.com', 'IPN Fraud Warning', $body);

        } else {

        //verified
        include 'connect.php';

            $sql = "INSERT INTO order VALUES 
                ('$txn_id', '$payer_email', '$mc_gross')";

           if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
              error_log(mysql_error());
              exit(0);
            }
        }

    } else {
        /*
        An Invalid IPN *may* be caused by a fraudulent transaction attempt. It's
        a good idea to have a developer or sys admin manually investigate any 
        invalid IPN.
        */
        mail('myemail@domain.com', 'Invalid IPN', $listener->getTextReport());
    }

    ?>
```

I have set my merchant acc IPN to listen to 'ipn.php' file.
As you can see if the payment is verified , i make a database query to insert a new row into ORDER table.

I go to index.html and clicked the buy now button , paid using my Buyer ID.

However,

I keep getting "Invalid HTTP request method" error in the errors log.

Anyone can help me spot the problem or i am doing it wrongly?
Thanks have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

try this ipn listner

```
 <?php
   //Build the data to post back to Paypal
    $postback = 'cmd=_notify-validate'; 

     // go through each of the posted vars and add them to the postback variable
     foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
          $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
          $postback .= "&$key=$value";
      }


     // Send to paypal or the sandbox depending on whether you're live or developing
     //$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);//open the connection
       $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if (!$fp) 
{
    // HTTP ERROR Failed to connect
    //error handling or email here
}
else // if we've connected OK
{
    fputs ($fp, $header . $postback);//post the data back
    while (!feof($fp)) 
    {
        $response = fgets ($fp, 1024);

        if (strcmp ($response, "VERIFIED") == 0) //It's verified
        {
           //if verified do something 
        }
        else if (strcmp ($response, "INVALID") == 0) 
        { 
            //the Paypal response is INVALID, not VERIFIED
            // This implies something is wrong 
        }
    } //end of while
    fclose ($fp);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's [PHP-PayPal-IPN](https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN) ! that will surely help you

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is because both the notify url and the return url are not pointing to a real website. Although I came here as I am finding the same issue (I'm testing in the sandbox environment with a local machine address, so need to find a way around to fix this as well)

http://mysite.com/ <-- I have here a 192 IP address :(